# The best way for inserting multiple object into array

Tags: javascript

I have a transformer helper function. It reduces over the array and transform key/value pairs. At the end of the loop there is the key 'EXAMPLE1' exists and I should insert two objects after the first and the second array(result) items. Right now, it works as expected, but I have concerns about - is it a good approach for using splice inside reduce in my case?

```
    const commonData = Object.entries(settings).reduce((result, [currentKey, currentValue]) => {
        if (currentKey === SETTINGS_FIELDS.EXAMPLE1) {
            const type = {
                key: myKey,
                value: myValue,
            }
            const code = {
                key: myKey,
                value: myValue,
            }

            const insertedData = result.splice(2, 0, type, code)

            return [...result, ...insertedData]
        }



        return result.concat({ key: transformToUpperCase(currentKey), value: currentValue })
    }, [])

    return [...commonData]
}
```

Comment: do you have some data - before and after the call?

Comment: If you have code that works, and you'd like a review of all aspects of the code, your question may be better off on [codereview.se]. I highly encourage you to review their help center before asking though.

Comment: It would be interesting to have a few examples of input & expected output, because the requirement to insert after the first two elements sounds weird. If you have two `EXAMPLE1` entries, would that work out as intended?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `insertedData` will always be an empty array, as `splice` returns an array with the *deleted* elements, but you don't delete any (the second argument you pass to `splice` is 0).

So you can do this without `splice` and without `insertedData`:

```
return [result[0], result[1], type, code, ...result.slice(2)]
```

If you want to stick to the *functional programming* paradigm, it is indeed a no-go to use `splice`. But even without that consideration, it seems to me that avoiding `splice` here has no performance downsides and does not make the code harder to read. So I see no reason why to keep it in.

A final remark on your code:

There is no reason to return a copy of `commonData` with `[...commonData]`. `commonData` can be returned as is as there is no other reference to it.